# my PHP file show the data from database before search

Tags: php

```
<?php 
    require_once( "member.php"); 
    $query="" ; 
    if(!empty($_GET[ "query"])) {
      $query=$ _GET[ "query"]; 
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Search Area</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1 align="center">Members</h1>

    <form class="modal-content" method="get" action="indexx.php">
        <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="query" value="<?php echo $query; ?>" placeholder="Enter Imei No./Job No." name="query">
            <button type="submit" value="Search">Check</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <p>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Birth Date</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                </tr>


    <?php //paging $page=1 ; if(!empty($_GET[ "page"])){ $page=$ _GET[ "page"]; } if($page==0 ){ $page=1 ; } $limit=1 0; $offset=( $page-1)*$limit; $data=g etMembers($query, $limit, $offset); $totalData=c ount($data); foreach( $data as $value){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value[ "firstname"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value[ "lastname"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value[ "gender"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value[ "birthdate"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $value[ "address"]; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } //Total All Rows $totalRows=g etMemberTotalRows($query); ?>

    </table>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i want to create search web for my members.. everything is ok but
my search php site show the data from database before i m search.. please help me.. i m new in php..
how to hide that data before i m click the check button?
sory for my bad english..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = getMembers($query, $limit, $offset);
```

Call that only when your search value `$_GET["data"]` is set

```
if(isset($_GET["query"]))
    $data = getMembers($query, $limit, $offset);
else
    die("Nothing to search for");   // Or anything else for that matter
```

Comment: °·♥·♡Τнäиκчöü♥·♡·° very much my problem solve! 